# Unable to get object/array size

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Background: I am using reactjs and my goal is to get data stored in firestore

i have an empty array which i am adding to, after which the array is returned

import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/storage"
import "firebase/firestore"

```
class firebaseclass {
  constructor() {
    if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }
  }

  getfirestore() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    var storearray = []
    db.collection("data").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        storearray.push(doc.data())
     });
    });
    return storearray
  }
}

export default new firebaseclass
```

In my homepage, i am calling the function as such

```
function App() {
  const [names, setnames] = useState({
  })

  var datadata = firebaseclass.getfirestore();
  console.log(datadata, "datadatadata")

  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is the console log result

```
[]
0: {hasstart: false, lat: ******, long: *******, name: "***", postalcode: ******, …}
1: {hasstart: false, lat: ******, long: ******, name: "chias crib", postalcode: ******, …}
2: {hasstart: false, lat: "test3", long: "test3", postalcode: 3, powerlevel: 3, …}
length: 3
__proto__: `Array(0)


"data data data"`
```

as you can see, i am receiving some form of result

when i

```
console.log(typeof(datadata), "data data data");
```

i receive

```
object data data data
```

which is odd, because i returned an array perviously

finally, when i try

```
  console.log(datadata.length, "data data data");
```

i receive

```
0 "data data data"
```

i have also tried

```
var size = Object.keys(datadata).length;


console.log(size, "datadatadata")
```

but i have received

```
0 "datadatadata"
```

i have also tried changing the empty array to an object, and returning an object instead of an array, but the above methods still do not work. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you return an empty array each time because the part where you're adding into array is done asynchronously.

```
getfirestore() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    var storearray = []

    // THIS PART RUNS ASYNC.
    db.collection("data").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        storearray.push(doc.data()). //. << ------ THIS IS CALLED SECOND
     });
    });

    return storearray // <<------- THIS IS CALLED FIRST
}
```

You will have to return a callback, a promise or use `async/await`

**Update** for async/await approach should be something like this:

```
async getfirestore() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const storearray = [];

    const querySnapshot = await db.collection("data").get();
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>  { storearray.push(doc.data()) });

    return storearray;
}
```

Then in your App:

```
async function App() {
  const [names, setnames] = useState({
  })

  var datadata = await firebaseclass.getfirestore();
  console.log(datadata, "datadatadata")
...
```

Comment: Hi, im sorry, i tried modifying my own code to try and get it to work, but i encountered some errors. Do u mind editing it in a way with async and await to make it work as intended?

Comment: @Dustyik I have updated the answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

First of **Arrays are objects in JS**.

Next if you notice the first line in your console, is an empty array.

```
[]
0: {hasstart: false, lat: ******, long: *******, name: "***", postalcode: ******, …}
1: {hasstart: false, lat: ******, long: ******, name: "chias crib", postalcode: ******, …}
2: {hasstart: false, lat: "test3", long: "test3", postalcode: 3, powerlevel: 3, …}
length: 3
__proto__: `Array(0)


"data data data"`
```

That's why you receive **count 0**, since the expected output comes last. Basically JS wont wait for the server, unless it was set to async. Please have a look at [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-from-callbacks-to-async-await-1cc090ddad99/) it might give you more idea what I am talking about.